# I have defined a class with attributes but when I put in a test code, it doesn't return anything

Tags: python

Please advise what I am doing wrong with my code. When I execute it, I get 'process finished with exit code 0'. My aim was to define that class BusStop with the given attributes and then test it. I have just started learning about classes and attributes and still don't seem to be getting the hang of it properly

```
class BusStop:
    def __init__(self, number, name, street, suburb):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.street = street
        self.suburb = suburb

stop = BusStop(1, "xyz", "xstreet", "xsuburb")
stop.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print to standard output, you need to use the `print` statement:

```
print(stop.name)
#xyz
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. If I may ask, is this how classes are usually tested? Is this the correct way of testing it

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `__str__` in your class so you will be able to show its properties.

See https://realpython.com/lessons/how-and-when-use-str/

```
class BusStop:
    def __init__(self, number, name, street, suburb):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.street = street
        self.suburb = suburb
    def __str__(self):
      return f'number: {self.number},name: {self.name},street: {self.street},suburb: {self.suburb}'

stop = BusStop(1, "xyz", "xstreet", "xsuburb")
print(stop)
```